# Set variables values of a list to another list variables values in Java

Tags: java

Here is my Allowance class

```
public class Allowance {
    private String Id;
    private String Name;
    private String Type;
    private String RemainingAmount;
    private String TotalAmount;
}
```

This is created list

```
public List<Allowance> getBList(){
    List<Allowance> BList = new ArrayList<>();
    List.add(new Allowance("5964852","Name1","DATA","10","458965"));
    List.add(new Allowance("651655","Name2","DATA","20","5481662"));
    List.add(new Allowance("123","Name3","VOICE","30","8889625"));
    List.add(new Allowance("123423","Name4","DATA","20","325489"));
    return BList;
}
```

Here is my Benefits class

```
public class Benefits {
    private String itemId;
    private String bName;
    private String remaining;
    private String bTotal;
}
```

So, I want to set Allowance class variables values to Benefits class variables values Like this

Id value  --> itemId value

Name value --> bName value

RemainingAmount value ---> remaining value

TotalAmount value ---> bTotal value

Then i want to return Benefits list like this

```
["itemId" : "5964852","bName": "Name1","remaining":"10","bTotal":"458965"]
```

Any one can help me ?

Comment: I am not quite sure I understand your question. Do you want a maper/transformer that, given an `Allowance`, creates a `Benefit`?

Comment: Would you please clarify what you mean by "set Allowance class name to Benefits class name"?  It's fairly trivial to create a new Benefits object from an Allowance object using a Benefit constructor that takes an Allowance as a parameter (or using a factory) - but it doesn't sound like that's what you want.

Comment: Sorry, but this question doesn't make sense.  You *cannot* change a class name.  And you *cannot* change a variable or field name.  But you can change the *value* of a field whose name is "name".

Comment: Yes **@Turing85**

Comment: Actually i want to set Allowance class variable value to Benefits class variable ***@StephenC***  ***@Tibrogargan***

Comment: @LTHLiyanage, the method getBucketList() is calling a constructor in Allowance that does not exist. List.add(new Allowance("5964852","Name1","DATA","10","458965")); can't work unless you create a constructor in the class Allowance that receives the values and initialize the appropriate variables. (Unless the code is there and you just omitted it from the code)

Comment: Also, is it the entire list that you want to clone to a list of Benefits or its just individual Allowance Objects?

Comment: i want to clone entire list @Kasalwe

Comment: You can add a method called clone in the Allowance class that returns a copy of the fields you are interested in as a new Benefits object. Inside both Allowance and Benefits you need to add constructors that initialize all the fields. To get a clone of the Arraylist, loops through the list and call clone on each list item storing them in a new list of type benefit.

Comment: You cannot set an `Allowance` class variable to a `Benefits` class variable unless there is some inheritance or implementation relationship defined for those classes (which there isn't in your question), the language simply does not allow it.  It might be an idea to explain the higher level problem you are trying to solve by performing such an operation.
It is of course possible to re--write your classes so there is a relationship, but it would require more knowledge of the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transfer the values from an Allowance instance by using the single arg constructor and then poplating the properties of the Benefits class from the Allowance instance that is passed in.
You can also override the toString method of the Benefits class to obtain the desired output. The clone method in the allowance class will take in the list you have already created to return a list of Benefits instances.

The Allowance class:

```
class Allowance {
    private String Id;
    private String Name;
    private String Type;
    private String RemainingAmount;
    private String TotalAmount;

    public String getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return Type;
    }

    public String getRemainingAmount() {
        return RemainingAmount;
    }

    public String getTotalAmount() {
        return TotalAmount;
    }

    public Allowance(String id, String name, String type, String remainingAmount, String totalAmount) {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Type = type;
        RemainingAmount = remainingAmount;
        TotalAmount = totalAmount;
    }

public List<Benefits> clone(List<Allowance> allowanceList){
        
        List<Benefits> benefitList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Allowance allowance : allowanceList){
            benefitList.add(new Benefits(allowance));
        }
        
        return benefitList;
    }
}
```

The benefits class:

```
class Benefits{

    private String itemId;
    private String bName;
    private String remaining;
    private String bTotal;

    public Benefits(Allowance allowance){

        this.itemId = allowance.getId();
        this.bName = allowance.getName();
        this.remaining = allowance.getRemainingAmount();
        this.bTotal = allowance.getTotalAmount();

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[ itemId : " + this.itemId + ", bName : " + this.bName + ", remaining : " + this.remaining + ", bTotal :" + this.bTotal + "]";
    }
}
```

To create the list of Benefit items, you could also create the following List directly:

```
      List<Benefits> bList = new ArrayList<>();

        Allowance a = new Allowance("5964852","Name1","DATA","10","458965");
        Allowance b = new Allowance("651655","Name2","DATA","20","5481662");
        Allowance c =  new Allowance("123","Name3","VOICE","30","8889625");
        Allowance d = new Allowance("123423","Name4","DATA","20","325489");

        bList.add(new Benefits(a));
        bList.add(new Benefits(b));
        bList.add(new Benefits(c));
        bList.add(new Benefits(d));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use stream and lambda is easy to realize it.

```java
List<Allowance> AList = BList.stream().map(B -> {
    new Allowance(
        B.getId(),
        B.getName(),
        B.getRemainingAmount(),
        B.bTotal())
}).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Answer (score 0):

So from what I read in the replies to your original question, you'd be looking for something along these lines;

1. You need to create getters for all the attributes of Allowance.
2. Then create a constructor that takes an Allowance object as a parameter.

   ```
    public Benefits (Allowance a) {

        this.itemId = a.getID;
        this.bName = a.getName;
        this.remaning = a.getRemainingAmount;
        this.bTotal = a.getTotalAmount;
    }
   ```